# When Authorization Policy is implemeneted, got internal server error instead of unauthroized status code. ASP.Net Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I am implementing the AuthorizationPolicy in ASP.Net core.

What I have done is here. I have inherited TokenRequirement from IAuthorizationRequirement and then created a handler for the TokenRequirement. Here is the code.

```
public class TokenRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}

public class TokenHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TokenRequirement>
{
    ITokenService tokenService;
    public TokenHandler(ITokenService tokenService)
    {
        this.tokenService = tokenService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tokenService));
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TokenRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            var httpContext = (DefaultHttpContext)context.Resource;

            if (httpContext != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]))
                    context.Fail();
                else
                {
                    string jwtToken = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
                    JwtSecurityToken token = tokenService.DecryptToken(jwtToken);
                    var claims = token.Claims;

                    if (token.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "role" && c.Value == @"XXXX Authentication1").Count() > 0)
                        context.Succeed(requirement);
                    else
                    {
                        context.Fail();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                context.Fail();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and then I have added these lines in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, FileTransferWebAPI.TokenHandler>();
```

and

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Token", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenRequirement()));
});
```

and also

```
[Authorize(Policy ="Token")]
    public class FileTransferController : ControllerBase
```

Now if the Token is successfully handled by TokenHandler, then I get success status code, 200, along with data, but if it is failed, it throws internal server error, 500.

Here is the exception description from Postman.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String. (Parameter 's')
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8EncodingSealed.GetBytes(String s)
   at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Main>$>b__1(JwtBearerOptions o) in D:\Projects\FileTransferWebAPI\FileTransferWebAPI\Program.cs:line 35
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.<>c__3`1.<GetOrAdd>b__3_0(String name, ValueTuple`2 arg)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd[TArg](String name, Func`3 createOptions, TArg factoryArgument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:6200
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.30.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.ONEXXnlb3dVGs0bcahCtD4EIvZoYMaYDVqV1XYabMRQVmoRMSeEUODtlhsZHOm0Nq2r6c3zBSy_g5j9bTyId-g
Postman-Token: d687b92f-0e65-45c8-a1ce-9d7c88d9dfd9
```

I had followed the following links.
1- https://medium.com/@samjwright/creating-a-custom-authorization-policy-in-net-core-5f2b053ce972
2- https://damienbod.com/2017/10/23/implementing-custom-policies-in-asp-net-core-using-the-httpcontext/

I am not sure what I am making the mistake.

Comment: I had a test in my side but didn't reproduce your issue. Since you mentioned you got the exception `System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String. (Parameter 's')`, could you please debug your custom `ITokenService` and find where it throws this `ArgumentNullException`?

Comment: I had a custom `TokenService` like below:

    `public class TokenService : ITokenService
        {
            public JwtSecurityToken DecryptToken(string token) {
                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
                return jwtSecurityToken;
            }
        }`

Comment: I have same DecryptToken method as you have shared. Is it working even if the JWT is invalid, does it show unauthorize status in response?

Comment: pls allow me to share what I did in my side... I didn't meet your issue...

Answer (score 0):

First, I have an .net 6 MVC project and integrate JWT auth. Then I used your code snippet to add the token handler. Here's the Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

SecurityService securityService = new(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SecurityService>();
 
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(securityService.Key);
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ThisismySecretKey")),
            //IssuerSigningKey = key,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, TokenHandler>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Token", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenRequirement()));
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITokenService, TokenService>();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Then in the `TokenHandler`, since the token itself is not important, so I changed it like below:

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TokenRequirement requirement)
{
    if (context != null)
    {
        var httpContext = (DefaultHttpContext)context.Resource;
        if (httpContext != null)
        {
            string jwtToken = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
            JwtSecurityToken token = tokenService.DecryptToken(jwtToken);
            var claims = token.Claims;
            if (token.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "role" && c.Value == @"XXXX Authentication1").Count() > 0)
                context.Fail();
            else
            {
                //context.Fail();
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                //throw new NullReferenceException("my custom message");
            }
                
        }
        else
            context.Fail();
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

And the TokenService:

```
public class TokenService : ITokenService
{
    public JwtSecurityToken DecryptToken(string token) {
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
        return jwtSecurityToken;
    }
}
```

The policy is assigned to an API which will return a string, when I set the handler as `context.Succeed(requirement);`, it will return success string. If I changed to  `context.Fail();`, it will give 401 error.

[image]
[image]

I also tried to reproduce the exception, I put the `[Authorize]` before the home page action method, then I got exception below, which is also different from yours, So I'm afraid you'd debug your code to find which line throw the `null exception` when you already had a token in your request header.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However unfortunately I was making another mistake. I was using AddJWTBearer function where I was setting the issuer, audience and key from configuration, but in the configuration, there were no settings for them. Although even I did not need any of them in any way in my app, but strangest thing is that, it was working fine when I called Success() on AuthorizationHandlerContext, but throwing exception when I called Fail().

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with your code snippet, so this is all I can do for you, sorry for it.